# Images Not Displaying On iOS 9 iPhone 4s and 5

Tags: xcode, image, swift, sprite-kit, ios-simulator

I just installed Xcode 7.0 and simulator 9.0. Since installing this, when using the iPhone 4s/ 5 simulator, any image that is fetched from the Assets.xcassets file, will not display on the simulator, however the node count at the bottom states that the nodes are present.

When using the iPhone 5s simulator however, the images then appear. Any image that is part of an atlas seems to display no problems, regardless of the simulator device, just the images from the Assets.xcassets file are not being displayed.

When I tested the app on my iPhone 5, the images appeared as normal. However, I don't have an iPhone 4s to test my app on, so the simulator is the only tool I have to use for that device.

My deployment target is 8.0 and device target is iPhone. Images are stored in the Assets.xcassets file at iPhone 2x and 3x, there are no 1x. I haven't installed iOS 9 on my phone yet, still iOS 8. I'm going to installed iOS 9 shortly to see if the images then disappear on an iOS 9 device.

Does anybody know why these image are not being displayed on the iPhone 4s/ 5 simulator?

**Edit:**

I've now installed iOS 9 on my phone and now the images don't appear on that, as well as the simulator. I've checked out previous apps I've created and even those apps have lost all there images, since updating to iOS 9.

Comment: I don't know if that helps but iPhone 5s i the first with 64bit.

Comment: spritekit in ios9 is terribly broken. More info/discussion/workarounds here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17463

Comment: I've reported the bug with apple. I'll see what they come back with.

For the time being though, I've changed the images to 2x universal from 2x iPhone, and this seems to display the images normally.

Comment: Please make sure you include a sample project in your radar.  Also, can you provide the radar number in a comment here?  Thanks.

Comment: The ID number I got was 22773576, would that be the radar number? I didn't include a sample when I reported the bug, as it is very easy to reproduce, but I'll attach the sample now.

Comment: i have similar issue. my image is not displaying in 4s but displaying in rest devices

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue.  It seems to be resolved for me by doing the following:

1. Changed my assets from image sets to a texture atlas, and within the atlas used the standard file naming conventions for device specific versions of a file, i.e. name@2x~iphone.png, etc.
2. Deleting the derived data from my Xcode project.  Go to Window -> Projects -> select your project and hit the delete button for your derived data.

I don't have any theories on why this worked.  And in retrospect I wonder if step 1 above was even necessary.  No guarantees that this will fix your issue, but it seemed to work for me.  Hope this helps.